# Voltage to frequency

Tags: voltage

I am wanting to know,

At what voltage input do I need to produce between 40 and 44 kHz using two quartz crystal resonators?

Just looking to the volts required (oscilating) for AC input, also what is the formula to converting how much power you need, I guess to collect a sound file of this grade of resonance if you would call it that

Thanks

Comment: The question doesn't seem to be clear.  Are you designing a circuit, or analyzing an existing one?  What are you ultimately trying to accomplish?  What's the goal?

Comment: Unfortunately, your question is meaningless. What do you want to do?

Comment: I want to put an input of said voltage to produce a frequency between 40-44kHz, what is the said voltage? And how did you work it out?

Comment: I'm just working out for curiosity sake an oscilating frequency range which could be anything in the frequency margin like 23-27kHz range I am only trying to figure out by using resonators how you find out what voltage you need for a desired frequency, like when a hand held controller for an aircraft is operated it uses a crystal to find that frequency range, I just want to determine how someone figures out the input in volts.

Comment: You don't. The frequency of oscillation of a crystal is pretty much independent of voltage, which is why the question is meaningless.

Answer (score 1):

A quartz crystal resonator (a crystal) oscillates at one specific frequency called its fundamental. If you want a 40kHz signal, you buy a 40kHz crystal. You can sometimes make a crystal oscillate at multiples of its fundamental, ie 80kHz, 120kHz, etc. but you cannot easily adjust a crystal to give a frequency in a range such as 40kHz to 44kHz. To do that you need a circuit or an IC called a Voltage Controlled Oscillator (VCO). As its name suggests, by changing the voltage you input to the VCO you will change the frequency it oscillates at. The voltage that you need to input for a specific frequency depends on the design of the VCO.

Have a look at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Voltage-controlled_oscillator